# Using decltype with member function definitions after declaration

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm using decltype for the return type of a member function, but the definition and declaration don't match. Here's some code:

```
template<typename T>
struct A {
    T x;
    auto f() -> decltype(x);
};

template<typename T>
auto A<T>::f() -> decltype(x) {
    return this->x;
}

int main() {}
```

This produces

```
test.cc:10:6: error: prototype for 'decltype (((A<T>*)0)->A<T>::x) A<T>::f()' does not match any in class 'A<T>'
test.cc:6:7: error: candidate is: decltype (((A<T>*)this)->A<T>::x) A<T>::f()
```

the difference being that the definition has `(A<T>*)0` where the declaration has `(A<T>*)this`. What gives?

Comment: What does `A<T>::x` instead of just `x` say. I don't know if it works or if it should be that way, though.

Comment: @ChristianRau That actually works, and is now the solution I've implemented until gcc fixes this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a bug in gcc 4.7 that I reported here: [bug #54359](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54359) (see bottom of the bug report). This particular case is accepted by gcc 4.6.

As a workaround, don't use a trailing return type and use the type of member `x` directly. In the example, this is simply `T`, but you can also convert more complex cases. For example, you can convert:

```
T x;
auto f() -> decltype(x.foo);
```

Into:

```
T x;
decltype(std::declval<T>().foo) f();
```

[std::declval](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval) is very useful here.