# Why does decltype not see the member declaration?

Tags: c++, c++11

Trying to compile this simple class:

```
#include <vector>
struct M
{
// interface
    auto begin() -> decltype(identities.begin())
    {
        return identities.begin();
    }
// implementation
private:
    std::vector<int> identities;
};
```

results in an error:

```
$ g++-510 where.cpp -std=c++11
where.cpp:57:35: error: ‘struct M’ has no member named ‘identities’
     auto begin() ->decltype(this->identities.begin())
                                   ^
where.cpp:57:35: error: ‘struct M’ has no member named ‘identities’

$ clang++ where.cpp -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic -Wextra
where.cpp:57:35: error: no member named 'identities' in 'M'
    auto begin() ->decltype(this->identities.begin())
                            ~~~~  ^
```

Why doesn't `decltype` see the class member?

Comment: In the meantime I found a workaround: declare the member variable ahead of the `decltype` use. But can somebody quote the standard which mandates this behavior? Or is it just easier for compiler writers?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/12362888/866732 ?

Comment: I don't think that's a duplicate, the member is declared above the function there.

Comment: @Bulletmagnet It's not a duplicate, as per TartanLlama's answer. Still nice to have the link here for others that did find the issue being because of it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From N3337 [basic.lookup.unqual]/7:

> A name used in the definition of a class X outside of a member function body or nested class definition shall be declared in one of the following ways:
>
> - before its use in class X or be a member of a base class of X, or...

Because the trailing return type is part of the function *declaration* rather than the *definition*, it can't look ahead to see what else is declared in the class, so you need to declare that member above the function declaration.

Answer (score 16):

If C++14 is available, you can omit the trailing return type, thus avoiding referencing a member outside function body and also making the code more compact:

```
auto begin() {
    return identities.begin();
}
```

In general it's more correct to use `decltype(auto)` for such forwarding methods, so return type can be a reference, though in this particular case it's the same (thanks to @Nawaz):

```
decltype(auto) begin() {
    return identities.begin();
}
```

Comment: Alas, we are already lucky just to be able to use C++11 (the only project in my company), so I'll have to go with TartanLlama :)

Comment: I think it should be `decltype(auto)`, though in this case `auto` would work.

Answer (score 2):

Move the declaration of the member before the function like so:

```
#include <vector>
struct M
{
   // implementation
   private:
      std::vector<int> identities;
   public:    
   // interface
     auto begin() -> decltype(identities.begin())
     {
        return identities.begin();
     }


};
```